# ¿Cómo mostrar los retorno de carro o de línea nueva en una variable tipo string en RubyOnRails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Tengo un string que puede tener retorno de carro o nueva línea, en ruby esto se resuelve así:

```
puts “hola \n mundo”
```

en rails se resuelve asi

```
<%= “hola <br> mundo”.html_safe  %>
```

pero la variable me viene en este formato

```
<%= “hola \n mundo”.html_safe  %>
```

y no muestra la línea nueva, lo resolví con este código:

```
<%= “hola \n mundo”.gsub("\n","<br>").html_safe %>
```

pero el cliente no quiere que modifique el contenido de la variable, ni si quiera para mostrarla. ¿qué me sugieren que pueda hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tus opciones van más por el lado de html/css.

La primera y más simple opción es que uses `<pre>`

```html
<p>Sin line break</p>
<div>
1ra linea
2da linea
</div>

<p>Con line break</p>
<pre>
1ra linea
2da linea
</pre>
```

La segunda es que uses el estilo `white-space: pre`

```css
div.line-break {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p>Con line break gracias a css</p>
<div class="line-break">
1ra linea
2da linea
</div>
```

En general la segunda opción es más recomendada, ya que es mucho mas versátil respecto al diseño que tendrá la información que muestres.